# Why does a wrapper that returns an inner function return a different copy of that inner function each time?

Tags: python

```
def outer():
    def inner(a):
        return a
    return inner

f = outer()
print(f)  # <function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x1044b61e0>

f2 = outer()
print(f2)  # <function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x1044b6268> (Different from above)
```

---

I know that f and f2 are different from each other.

But can someone tell me a precise explanation why they are different from each other?

Thank You

Comment: "I know that they are different but can someone tell me why they are different" I'm struggling to read that in a way that isn't directly contradictory.

Comment: Every time you call `outer()` it creates a new closure for `inner()`.

Comment: It will be to do with different stack frames.

Comment: Each time you call `outer()`, a new version of `inner()` gets created. That is, you `def inner` block gets executed fresh.

When you print them out, it's showing you that these new instances have different memory locations.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It's not contradictory. He can see that they're different, but he doesn't understand *why*.

Comment: Hey guys, I jsut found that without the `return` statement, the id of `inner` function when `outer` is being run multiple times is the same `id` value. Is that expected? I'm curious if someone can explain the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Update: I posted an answer to expound on my findings. This was certainly an interesting case and I don't have an answer for the noticed behavior right off the top of my head.

Comment: I haven't noticed it stated in any comment or answer yet, but an important detail is that functions in Python (as well as other languages such as JS) are Objects.  Each call to `outer()` causes a new instance of the function object `inner()` to be created in memory, and those instances will persist as long as the references to them in `f` and `f2` are in scope.  It's not much different from if `outer()` was returning instances of a class

Answer (score 1):

The `inner` function is defined in the `outer` function. A new instance of this function is re-created every time you call `outer`.

Consider the following function:

```py
a = 2

def not_so_inner():
    return a
```

You would expect it to always return `2`, since `a` is a module variable.

Now, if I write the following function:

```py
def outer(a):
    def inner():
        return a

    return inner

f1 = outer(1)
f2 = outer(2)
```

`f1` and `f2` are both a representation of the `inner` function, but bound to a different context where the `a` variable has a different value.

The return function must carry the outer context, so they are different instances of the function defined in the `outer` function.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that without the `return` statement involved, the `id` of the inner fuction `inner` is the same value, when `outer()` is called multiple times. This indicates that the `inner` function is actually pointing to the same reference value in memory.

```py
>>> def outer():
...     print('outer() is being called.')
...     class A:
...         ...
...     def inner(a):
...         return a
...     print('id of class A:', id(A))
...     print('id of function inner():', id(inner))
...
>>> outer()
outer() is being called.
id of class A: 2098069832976
id of function inner(): 2098062549056
>>> outer()
outer() is being called.
id of class A: 2098069814096
id of function inner(): 2098062549056
```

Notice that the line `id of function inner(): ...` indicates that the `id` values for `inner()` are the same in either case.

When you introduce a `return` statement, then things become a little more interesting. It looks like the `id` value is different each time, which indicates a new `inner()` function is being created on each invocation of `outer()`.

```py
def outer():
    print('outer() is being called.')

    class A:
        ...

    def inner(a):
        return a

    print('  id of class A:', id(A))
    print('  id of function inner():', id(inner))

    return inner


inner1 = outer()
inner2 = outer()
inner3 = outer()
print()
print(id(inner1))
print(id(inner2))
print(id(inner3))
```

Sample output:

```
outer() is being called.
  id of class A: 2175736425280
  id of function inner(): 2175746787792
outer() is being called.
  id of class A: 2175736423360
  id of function inner(): 2175746786496
outer() is being called.
  id of class A: 2175736424320
  id of function inner(): 2175746788080

2175746787792
2175746786496
2175746788080
```

Now I'm not entirely sure if this post answers your question, however it is certainly food for thought and for future consideration.

Using the builtin `id()` function in Python, you can confirm that a new `inner()` function is being created on each run, at least in regards to the second case above.